# Why (argv[1] == "a") returns false when set the 1st argument with "a"

Tags: c, argv

I try to parse command line arguments in Clang,

```
int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    if (av[1] == "a")
        printf("yes\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the `./a.out a`, nothing printed. `(av[1] == "a")` returns false. Why?

Comment: Strings in C don't compare this way: consider `if (strcmp(av[1], "a") == 0)` to test for "yes".

Comment: `av[1] == "a"` compares pointers, not the _string_ contents.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood type of `argv[1]`.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but then you must also have misunderstood type of `"a"` in the same way.